# How to create a new table from an existing table in R, using multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted to create a new table OR dataframe from an existing dataframe.

My original dataframe looks like the below:

| fruit | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| banana | 4 | 7 | 3 |
| lime | 8 | 10 | 5 |
| orange | 2 | 6 | 8 |
| grape | 7 | 5 | 10 |

I would like it to look like this:

| id | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | apple |
| 2 | apple |
| 3 | apple |
| 3 | banana |
| 4 | banana |
| 5 | lime |
| 5 | grape |
| ... | ... |

I know how to rename columns so renaming to id is fine. I just don't know how to pull the data from the dataframe to create a new table as I am fairly new to R.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

read_table("fruit   col1    col2    col3
apple   1   3   2
banana  4   7   3
lime    8   10  5
orange  2   6   8
grape   7   5   10") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-fruit, 
               values_to = "id") %>%  
  select(id, fruit)

# A tibble: 15 × 2
      id fruit 
   <dbl> <chr> 
 1     1 apple 
 2     3 apple 
 3     2 apple 
 4     4 banana
 5     7 banana
 6     3 banana
 7     8 lime  
 8    10 lime  
 9     5 lime
```